CS-Script - An Interesting Problem (Records/Columns Missing upon return to C# program)
I have an application that makes a call to a routine in a Script. I pass a DataSet to that routine - and it creates a Datatable - gives it a Name - and then uses the DataTable.COPY() routine to copy the already existing datatable (call it X) to the new one I created in the CS-Script routine.
However, when the script completes and returns to the calling program - the Datatable still exists - but it has no columns or rows... ??  Yet they existed while in the Script (I used MessageBox.Show to check)
C# Application
    Creates DataSet - and DataTable X
    Call CS-Script
        Creates DataTable Y - and adds to the Dataset that was passed into this script routine
        Runs the Copy() method of the datatable to duplicate Table X into Y
        I check the Cols and Rows - and they are what they should be (6 Cols and ~2000 rows)
    Call Passes back to my C# application 
        DataTable Y still exists - but no Cols or Rows ???
    

Now what is strange is that I have other scripts that take in the DataSet - and modify a DataTable (add a column and put values in it) - and they are fine when the call returns to the C# application from the Script.
Anyone have an idea of why I am losing the Column definitions and Rows from the COPY() method called in the CS-SCript routine?
The script that I am calling is :
This is the script that I am calling from the C# app.
    using System;
    using System.Data;
    using System.IO;
    using CSScript_Types;
    using System.Windows.Forms;
    using InSight;
    
    //  This is the class that does the Real work of the CS Script After Query work
    public class AfterTableScripts : iAfterTableStuff
    {
        // This is the generic routine that is called from InSights Into Data
        // Return value is string so that we can handle Bool, string, number, etc. 
        public CSScriptReturnValueClass AfterTableProcess(DataSet CurrDataSet, string CurrTableName, Form_InSightsMain MainForm)
        {
            CSScriptReturnValueClass ReturnRec = new CSScriptReturnValueClass();
            try
            {
                // Here is the code to be run after the Table is created in the dataset
                DataTable QHRInvoices = CurrDataSet.Tables["QHRInvoices"];
                DataTable DupTable = CurrDataSet.Tables.Add("DupsTable");
                DupTable = QHRInvoices.Copy();
                DupTable.TableName = "DupsTable";
                
                // Now Setup the Return Value 
                ReturnRec.Success = true;
                ReturnRec.ReturnValue = "";
                ReturnRec.ErrorMsg = "";
            }
            catch (Exception Ex)
            {
                // Now Setup the Return Value 
                ReturnRec.Success = false;
                ReturnRec.ReturnValue = "";
                ReturnRec.ErrorMsg = Ex.Message;
            }
            return ReturnRec;
        }
    }

And here is the calling code in the C# application:
        CSScriptReturnValueClass ReturnValue = new CSScriptReturnValueClass();
        //string ReturnValue;
        dynamic AfterTableScript = CSScript.Evaluator.LoadCode(CurrCode);
        ReturnValue = AfterTableScript.AfterTableProcess(CurrDataSet, CurrTableName, MainForm);

        if (ReturnValue.Success)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            // Need to Change this to a Logging routine
            FlexibleMessageBox.Show("Failure of CS Script:   Error: " + ReturnValue.ErrorMsg, "CodeRunAfterQuery - Message");
            return false;
        }


How are you passing data and how are you returning it from the script? Post the relevant  code so we can see what's actually happening.

Alejandro - a good point - the code is now posted above in an edit to the original post.
